# Is adding a couple of keywords in the footer (no links) considered wrong doing?

Tags: google, keywords, ranking, penalty

Many posts claim that putting links with keywords in the footer is not considered a good practice by Google. Some claim Google may penalize you.

But, is adding a couple of keywords without links in the footer considered a bad practice?  I do notice that Google picks better ads, but does it trigger ranking penalties? How many keywords would be considered too much? Should I remove them overall?

Here is a page example: http://myworldclocks.tostaky.biz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google views "keyword stuffing" as using keywords ways that are not natural.  Placing a list of keywords at the bottom of a page is certainly not natural.  You wouldn't be doing that if you weren't trying to rank for those keywords.

On the other hand, a small list (less than ten) of relevant keywords is unlikely to get you penalized, so your approach isn't a horrible one.

Still, it would be better to find a way to use those keywords in text on the page that is meant for users.  For example, you seem to have calculators on your website.  Users would benefit from instructions on how those calculators work and how they can use them.  You could work those keywords into the text of the instructions.

Comment: If it looks stupid to a customer it makes you look stupid to Google.

Comment: @FiascoLabs If only people understood that what's best for users is not coincidentally best for Google.